# Is it possible to extracz a zip file by file to file

Tags: javascript, php, zip

Hy
I have a question, is it possible to unzip a file via php but by file to file? I read some some zip Exempels in the php Manuals but i need a Way to extracz one file and than the other file. 
For example:
I have a zip file with many Folders and in this Folder are some pictures. Now i want to extracz the First zip item and check:
If it is a Folder 
If true than create a new file, extracz the Folder, create a new Folder in this Folder and save there the new file
If it is a file, than check size and Type
If this is correct than do something with this file
Next item

I als wantask if it is possible to check via javascript the zip file?
I readed something about a zip Library 
I only want to read all files and check size and Type before uploaded

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? Can you post that code?

Comment: No, i want to ASK if this is a Lot of work or it is a easy work

Comment: okay, the php code is finished, but js is missing